# Get email address from email body in outlook vba

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I've been working on a macro to get the email addresses from emails contained in a specific folder.

I am able to get to that folder and get all the items (emails) in it, and while the code executes fine, extracting what I need, it stops at around 1273 email addresses retrieved.

The folder contains about 96,870 emails. I have gone through my logic and I think I have no errors, but it still falls short of going through all the emails.

This is my code:

```
Sub GetUndeliverables()
On Error Resume Next
    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim location As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim text As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim regEx As Object
    Dim olMatches As Object
    Dim strBody As String
    Dim email As String
    Dim foldCount As Long
    Dim badEmails() As String

    Dim Session As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Report As String
    Dim Accounts As Outlook.Accounts
    Dim currentAccount As Outlook.Account

    Set Session = Application.Session
    Set Accounts = Session.Accounts

    j = 1
    For Each currentAccount In Accounts
        If currentAccount.Session.Folders.Item(j).Name = "REDACTED" Then
            Set location = currentAccount.Session.Folders.Item(j)
        End If
        j = j + 1
    Next

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    'Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set location = location.Folders("Bandeja de entrada").Folders("Remover 2014")

    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    'set the regular expression
    With regEx
        .Pattern = "\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Global = True
    End With

    If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("No item selected")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If location Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Target folder not found!", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Error"
    End If

    i = 1
    xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    xlApp.Application.Visible = True

    foldCount = location.Items.Count

    ReDim badEmails(1 To foldCount)

    For Each olMail In location.Items
        strBody = olMail.Body
        Set olMatches = regEx.Execute(strBody)
        If olMatches.Count >= 1 Then
            badEmails(i) = olMatches(o)
        End If
        xlApp.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) = badEmails(i)
        i = i + 1
    Next

    Set olMail = Nothing
    Set location = Nothing
    Set ns = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You have `On Error Resume Next` which is not the sharpest tool in the draw, try debugging your code.

Comment: with @PaulFrancis advice and also add `option Explicit on top` and then see the error your getting

Comment: I've managed to narrow down the issue to the fact that in one email, it comes up between angle brackets <>, and that's when code stops. Any ideas on how to modify the RegEx to account for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I managed to figure this one out:

When some emails bounce back, they seem to fail to include a **"To"** field, so Outlook does not consider that a `MailItem`.

Since `olMail` had been declared as an `Outlook.MailItem`, when iterating through the `Items` collection, it would exit the sub once it found one such occurrence.

To fix this, simply change the type of `olMail` to `Object`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating through each Outlook item:

```
 For Each olMail In location.Items
    strBody = olMail.Body
    Set olMatches = regEx.Execute(strBody)
```

I'd recommend using the [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869662(v=office.15).aspx)/[FindNext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862482(v=office.15).aspx) or [Restrict](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869597(v=office.15).aspx) methods of the Items class. Also you may find the [AdvancedSearch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866933(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Application class helpful.